# Вид сказуемого: ПГС или СГС

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Как бы вы охарактеризовали вид сказуемого в этом предложении?

> Он почувствовал необходимость расчесться единожды навсегда со своею
>   молодостью и круто поворотить свою жизнь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Он **почувствовал необходимость расчесться** единожды навсегда со своею молодостью и круто **поворотить** свою жизнь.*

**Однородные** **составные глагольные** сказуемые:

**Вспомогательная часть - почувствовал необходимость** - фразеологизм (=захотел, решил).Грамматическое значение необходимости.

2 инфининива - расчесться и поворотить.Лексическое значение СГС.

Comment: Спасибо. Этот ответ я и хотел услышать. Просто одна знакомая (филолог) утверждала, что это ПГС.  Хотелось услышать, есть ли еще кто-то, кто  такого же мнения.

Comment: @Серж я бы относил это к ПГС, например. Потому что расчесться — это не какое-то отдельное "однородное сказуемое", а вполне себе отнесенное к слитой конструкции "почувствовал необходимость", определяющее последнее. По-школьному, конечно, трудно пытаться отнести это к "члену предложения". Но не сказуемое это, а определение как минимум.

Comment: ПГС было бы, если фразеологизмом была бы вся фраза -Он ещё долго нам мозолил глаза (надоедал).

Comment: Если считать сказуемым только " почувствовал необходимость", то само действие непонятно без "расчесться" и "поворотить", без них отдельно стоять не может, поэтому такие сказуемые и есть слитные сочетания, СГС, где фразеологизм выступает в роли вспомогательного глагола со значением решения, желания. Это как "Я решил расчесться и поворотить", ведь это точно СГС  - он решил, и он будет рассчитываться и поворачивать судьбу, а определением было бы "Ему внушили желание расчесться и поворотить судьбу" - разные деятели.

Comment: @Аеr, конструкция близка к расщепленному предикату (глагольно-именной оборот) напр.: иметь желание - желать, нанести ранение - ранить. Грамматически такие обороты рассматриваются как осложненный вариант простого глагольного сказуемого.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд это СИС. С дополнительным осложнением в составе именной части. "Почувствовать" - глагол как правило модальный, сам по себе смыслового действия не выражает. Поэтому "необходимость" - часть сказуемого. Судя по всему, именная часть тоже составная: "необходимость расчесаться". Но тут уже могут быть варианты.

Это навскидку.